# Backup projet file 7.0 to 6.2 version (Talend Open Studio for data integration)

Tags: talend

By opening my project with the 7.0 Talend version, it has been converted into 7.0 format, now I want to go back on the 6.2, but I have an error message saying that the projet has been opened in a posterior version.

I did a recovery of my projet from the moment where my files weren't converted but i still have the same error message.

I suppose some extras files are used somewhere else of the workspace, but I dont know where.

If you have any idea..

Comment: Are you using Talend Open Studio or Platform version ? How many jobs do you have ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "a recovery" ? Did you export your project from the 6.2 ?

Comment: Im using Talend Open Studio.
About "a recovery" : I did a robocopy from a windows save on all my workspace

Comment: How many jobs do you have ?